# ISNULL and UPPER with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, isnull

I have a query (condensed version - edited to add the SUM items for clarity) -

```
SELECT STORENBR AS "Store", 
DISPENSER AS "Model",
UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR) AS "Serial",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='CCE' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 CCE gallons",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='BAC' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 BAC gallons",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='844' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 844 gallons" 
FROM table
GROUP BY STORENBR, DISPENSER, UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR);
```

works just fine.  But now I have to account for NULL values in the Serial Number field.  I tried

```
SELECT STORENBR AS "Store", 
DISPENSER AS "Model",
ISNULL(UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR), "N/A") AS "Serial",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='CCE' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 CCE gallons",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='BAC' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 BAC gallons",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='844' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 844 gallons"  
FROM table
GROUP BY STORENBR, DISPENSER, UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR);
```

and Oracle SQL Developer is telling me ISNULL won't work with GROUP BY.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Why not simply do `SELECT DISTINCT`? (No need for that GROUP BY since no aggregate functions are involved.)

Comment: I agree with using `distinct`, but if you want to use `group by`, use the entire expression instead -- `group by ... ISNULL(UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR), "N/A")`

Comment: @jarlh - Left out with my condensed query are several CASE steps for adding up gallons dispensed by each machine.

Comment: Are there any aggregate functions? (Like MIN(), MAX(), SUM() etc.)

Comment: @jarlh - already answered about aggregate functions, but I edited my query to add them so you see it.

Comment: You mention sql developer and your syntax looks like Oracle but you tagged this with sql server. Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: @SeanLange - Oracle SQL Developer - I never tagged it with SQL-Server.  If that tag was thrown in there, it was by mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it in a single query with adding the whole expression:

```
SELECT STORENBR AS "Store", 
       DISPENSER AS "Model",
       NVL(UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR), "N/A") AS "Serial",
       SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='CCE' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 CCE gallons",
       SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='BAC' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 BAC gallons",
       SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='844' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 844 gallons"  
 FROM table
GROUP BY STORENBR, DISPENSER, NVL(UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR), "N/A");
```

Comment: Thank you - this is my first time hearing about NVL

Comment: @BigRedEO No problem :) If you see hear for the first time for NVL, I would also recommend you to read a bit about NVL2 as it can also be useful in similar circumstances (and also COALESCE, but I guess you might have seen it in other SQL languages).

Answer (score 2):

Not `ISNULL` but `NVL`, two times - in the `select` and `group by` statements

```
SELECT STORENBR AS "Store", 
DISPENSER AS "Model",
NVL(UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR), "N/A") AS "Serial",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='CCE' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 CCE gallons",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='BAC' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 BAC gallons",
SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='844' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 844 gallons"  
FROM table
GROUP BY STORENBR, DISPENSER, NVL(UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR), "N/A");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query up oin a derived table, then do the GROUP BY:

```
select "Store", 
       "Model",
       "Serial",
       SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='CCE' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 CCE gallons",
       SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='BAC' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 BAC gallons",
       SUM (CASE WHEN CLRNTSYS ='844' THEN GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 844 gallons" 
from
(
    SELECT STORENBR AS "Store",
           DISPENSER AS "Model",
           ISNULL(UPPER(TINTERSERIALNBR), "N/A") AS "Serial",
           CLRNTSYS,
           GALLONS 
    FROM table
) dt
GROUP BY "Store", "Model", "Serial"
```

Comment: Had to take back upvote, as it was based on how the question was originally tagged.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about oracle to know if the answer is still good for that environment.

Comment: This still doesn't cover the ISNULL substitution for me

Comment: Oops. Now fixed.